# My erd.pdf was garbled. I want to solve this problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solidus

I’m beginner.
I study Ruby.

I want to see ERD.

So,I did this command.

```
brew install Graphviz
bundle exec erd --filename=tmp/erd
```

I was able to display erd.pdf,but it was garbled.

```
%���������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
    x�Z�r���+�U��x���Le��]�b�������ZN<��|Kν.�&���T�T��&pߏ�~���'��۽�۽6���b�2i��mL�;�f��O7��Ʒ.vAw�k���/7�7���u���w�Ϧu�y��|}(�C!~)D��j�:?��ܒ�v�؇rO�/O�����TbC������_�_6�E{�E�{Ltk���W;�͔vn~�be��h���:��%&���C��t��ؠ�ho&h�Lҹ�&�V�]Z�Q�1�ͷ�P����w�,<Jli���]aaw��o��&�q�v#�{h�{1�(\��U�i��-��I��Ĵ����[Y-

��U��F=�Ё�y��`�Q�+����:��B�=�����e�r�63���we67e6�w�\���'���8S�5�@�[�~p�޵��<s�4~yy����Nm��\���R������<���v��t���ܻPt�?]���<�z<�]�J�1��!�(��k��A��K�BJ���n�
pqĬ���I'���x����.�]��T��    w�Mq�r��Y,,Y��[�C��@N?� H����R��(z�v�G�#;��ο����Q�������ߗ["�4�f�KŃ�z���з��{J{U+6]
�%���� ���V����1E�/r��o禮9�?
Up-aδ34�^�}��)�u���Q?�]~v�=[Y��
*�UE��ME�(�y����9S:���j�}Jf]���R+�hy����>����-��c���)w)�s��H��P�_�ib�x�}������e�Z)`̀�K�,Z�"�gRX�����,|�w�}�^��~�+ձ4��F��    ���Eչ�?^�I�~�:P�#��'Վ\��p(A4w�nl���"�A�.\�nts�n�A
U7�&%aHpUmeAO��!���F�%�f��A�䜂�0[Q^o��+ƅj?�c�y�d�ѵ�u*a-�y �����cIµ�3Wq'�/���rˡ�e�q��!m�H!$������X�"#��x��4W��"�0Y�����[Ia���Ӄ~BB C�L�R�0�[�
\��Ιd=o�Z�Wx8��]k�.U�d��Μpp�'��&���yobg�f���ڈ=A?Z�db�m���5�؇�"��@�0�����5Ym�1�<Ժ�N���.H(^MV�;Ѐj;�0đ���cߩG��J8Zwck�:�?�7��cc�:/گ��z�k �ͭ�vL�w�Fm�5#�n��/1�x5R��]�C�T�h�Bi�R��R^U(��h'��$��U��b��Hw�aچ���I���FIq���CG��4�DC�M�j�ܑ��:Q��s�j;�i\q<�+IK��e-}n
\i�&k�:'�#_~B�zY;�d&��Iypܡšv�L��w��?���Ms��0���TA�n�X�x̉S��n�zI���a�ނ;y�ܑ��,|��/"�Z���۱�\Tl]Ux�k��t��Y���LK�q�*�}.��y)ѢQ�(U��iǩ&�����0�2c:�D�dY�7�Gݙ�VԱ�l���"���V�jZ�]���RM#i�ڻ5w��HX��u��.P�n����GFZ�?q��Y��s���N�!��c�p�8XLX85��`\Ⱕ���X]��5�S��ah߯�t�(��ek�j�z�H�9p   E�]��__-�ΥkU��#v��Ev�����L��R�q��VV���k�DHF��g�)^ .p�+������æ��<XG�K��)eݽRZp���)i;au��4|ޢ�պ�CƢ.�W��vG�xв<s~ap���F��H��]����:)��v�#�2�N�I�+]"*Z�0�����$�t|n|����Ԙ�4�`eD������A(�G��s}��X@'�1Q��'}j9�#��E�$�O9��S��}j�S2�6rW�����TЉ�$��v��hA>#� m���C�[��Qku�Y����C�u,�ֵ:�s��$�\i�S��ڮ�N���Z��Tmm�C�P��E�҆�πo�x@E�`t�Z��  �c%�����"o|� "$З=�S��@�@G��:(!D@<
```

I want to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean, "garbled"? What version of Ruby? What version of erd? What version of Rails?

Comment: Ruby 2.5.1.
Rails 5.2.1.
I use vscode.

Comment: add garbled code.

Comment: How did you try to view the pdf? It’s a document that you have to view with your operating systems pdf viewer; you can’t render a pdf on the command line. Find the file and double click it to open it.